# Do not understand algebra technique used to computer summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, summation

I am going through a practice exam for my Discrete Mathematics class and do not understand the algebra used in the following summation computation.

Summation to compute:

[image]

Answer:

[image]

What I don't understand:

How exactly do they get they separate $\frac{1}{j(j+1)}$ into $\frac{1}{j} - \frac{1}{j+1}$ ?  The algebra used there is tripping me up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac ab- \frac cd=\frac{ad-bc}{bd}$$

$$\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)\cdot1-n\cdot1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{n+1-n}{n(n+1)}=
\frac1{n(n+1)}$$